# Detecting attribute update in sibling Lightning component when passed as reference

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-events, aura-attribute

I have a parent component which has an object attribute called "record".
This is passed into two instances of another component as a reference.
In child component #1 one of the fields is changed on the record via a component.getReference('v.record') assignment to another child component (text field).
The change handler responds in component #1 to signify that it has been updated however not in component #2.

How can I have the second child component detect the same change?

Parent Component:

```
<force:recordData
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    fields="Test_Multi__c,Test_Dep_1__c,Test_Dep_2__c"
    mode="EDIT"
    targetFields="{!v.record}" />

<aura:if isTrue="{! null != v.record }">
    <c:Field mode="edit" sObjectName="{!v.sObjectName}" record="{! v.record }" name="Test_Dep_1__c" />
    <br />
    <c:Field mode="edit" sObjectName="{!v.sObjectName}" record="{! v.record }" name="Test_Dep_2__c" />
    <!-- <br />
    <c:Field mode="edit" sObjectName="{!v.sObjectName}" record="{! v.record }" name="Test_Multi__c" /> -->
</aura:if>
```

Child Component:

```
<aura:component controller="Field_LEx" implements="force:hasSObjectName,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute type="sObject" name="record" description="RecordWrapper" />

    <!-- Either FieldWrapper, or sObjectName and FieldName are required -->
    <aura:attribute type="FieldDefinition" name="field" description="Field Definition" />
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="name" description="Field Name" />
    <aura:attribute type="Aura.Component[]" name="fieldComponent" description="Field Component" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }" />
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{! v.field }" action="{! c.handleFieldDefinitionChange }" phase="bubble" />
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{! v.record }" action="{! c.handleRecordDefinitionChange }" phase="bubble" />
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{! v.mode }" action="{! c.handleModeChange }" phase="bubble" />

    {! v.fieldComponent }
</aura:component>
```

The v.fieldComponent attribute is populated, dynamically, with a picklist component - the value of which is passed using `config.value = component.getReference( 'v.record.' + field.Name );`

Comment: maybe you can include your components (minimal reproduceable code sample) ? it will be easier for other to provide feedback, based on what you have.

Comment: I have added parts of the code to the original question.

Comment: To communicate between siblings either you have to use application event which is not good with respect to performance, you need to call a component event and from parent lightning component communicate to otger chields if you put your component hierarchy it will be easy to answer. For attribute change  it propagate from patent to chield and reverse is not true for that you need component events

Comment: The parent component should be irrelevant in the process. The hierarchy is described in the original post: parent container component -> two instances of the child component -> instance of an inputText component. The record attribute is passed through all of these by reference and is changed in every single component. If it is genuinely the case that only the active component can detect said change, it is a massive flaw in the design of Lightning.

Comment: This is a bit confusing, I don't understand in the connection between the childComponent code that you have entered in the post and the instances of `c:Field` that you start on the parent. something is missing hee

Comment: What is confusing? The code is verbose. The literal issue is that the change is occurring in a sibling component as expected but where the event for the change is not firing.

Comment: @ThomasMcFarlane It's typically `name` then `type`, minor confusion there. Omitted is the `c. handleRecordDefinitionChange` and `c.init` where we can see how you're assigning `v.record` and `v.fieldComponent`, respectively. FYI, `v.fieldComponent` would be more aptly named `v.body` (in comparison to how Salesforce builds their components) as it's the body of the component you're creating. And `FieldDefinition` is not an attribute type...

Comment: FieldDefinition is a custom wrapper. v.fieldComponent is also a custom variable, not the full component body - and it won't be as there will be other elements in the containing component. v.record is also assigned in the force:recordData component which is a standard Salesforce utility. c.handleRecordDefinitionChange is simply a console.log of the event data/to tell me something has changed. The code works from a generation/visual perspective perfectly. The issue is that the event of an object changing does not occur on one of the components the handler is registered on; even though it changes